# Ubuntu and other distros get stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb, plymouth

I've tested:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ubuntu 15.10
- Elementary OS 0.4
- Linux Mint 18

All these distributions get suck at the same part: splash screen. I press ESC to watch what's going on in the terminal and all I get is a recurrent message:

```
NMI watchdog: Bug: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s!
```

[image]

I can't even get to the options screen to choose to install, try, etc... It directly doesn't load the system. My laptop specifications are the following:

- Already installed Windows 7 in main SSD.
- SSD Samsung 128GB / HGST 1TB
- Intel Core i7 6700HQ 2.6GHZ (4 physical cores, 4 logical cores)
- Two USB 3.1 ports and two USB 3.0 ports. (Trying to run Ubuntu using
  USB)
- NVidia GTX970M 3GB

I'm just trying to run a Live USB! I can't even run the Live USB...

What the heck is happening!?

Comment: It looks like it's a as-yet-unresolved, high-priority bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405 . It's *possible* that Ubuntu 16.10 might work better for you, since it uses a newer kernel, if you want to give it a try

Comment: This person says they solved the error by replacing their computer's power supply: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211

Comment: @NickWeinberg I'll try 16.10 and post results after. Thank you. Regarding power supply, I've got a laptop and I don't understand the relation between the power supply and this bug. It happens the same with AC connected or just using the battery.

Comment: Can you try plugging the USB stick into a USB 2.0 port? I've had problems with bootable USB sticks and USB3 ports...

Comment: @AndroidDev I thought about it too but sadly (in this case in particular) all my USB ports are 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid - Can you try a live DVD then?

Comment: @AndroidDev No optical drive on my laptop. The only way would be running from my secondary HDD (SATA).

Comment: @NickWeinberg Surprisingly it worked with 16.10. I guess it's due to updated drivers in new kernel. Thank you.

Comment: @NickWeinberg - I guess you should write an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it running using a higher version of Ubuntu distribution. The version used is **Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak)**.

I guess the problem was that my hardware wasn't supported yet in lower versions.

It seems that conflictive hardware could be:

- Lastest Intel processors (Skylake)
- Hight performance graphic cards (Mine is GTX 970M)
- NVMe and newer PCIe components.